# How to store changed data in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project in ASP.net.  I have a method that sends an email that the username has changed.  I want to call this method in the action of the controller if the username has changed.  How do I store the previous username and then compare it to the new username when it's posted?

Edit: Perhaps I shouldn't say "store".  I'm basically looking for a way to keep the information to compare later.  I'm considering hidden values however, I'm a bit unsure on how to bind the hidden value to the model being passed to the view and then post.

Comment: How you implement this is going to be _highly_ dependent upon your specific implementation. What are you currently using to store your username? Is this the user changing their own username, or is this an administrative form for changing the username of other users?

Comment: I have a database storing the values.  Perhaps I shouldn't say store, more like contain the information to compare later.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a database for that. MSSQL is typically paired with ASP.NET MVC.

Microsoft created Entity Framework to make a seamless integration between code and database. You should start with that tutorial if you are not familiar with the process of integrating a database.

[Getting Started with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli)

Comment: Thank you for your answer however, I don't want to make a database call if it's not necessary.  Is there a way to keep a record of the previous username and then when I'm in the action after post, compare to the new value.  Thank you.

Comment: You mean, as in using the Session to store it?

Comment: Hm I don't think a session variable is what I'm looking for.  I will try the mentioned solutions.  Thank you.